# Cannot Get Image To Display On Top Of Other Image

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to position the image on top of the image, following StackOverflow question 27609816 (positioning the scalable image on top of another image), but cannot get css to work.
My second image displays inline to the right of the first image.
I'm assigning a class to the second image as follows -

```css
.earth {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100;
  left: 0;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

#topDiv {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 205px;
  background-image: url(/I/starry_sky.jpg);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

```html
<div id="topDiv">
  <img src="I/map.jpg" width="900" height="205" align="top"/>
  <img class="earth" src="I/earth1.gif" align="top"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, never mind. I knew as soon as I asked for help, I'd figure it out myself.

Answer (score 1):

```css
/*NORMAL STYLING*/

.main {
  text-align: center;
}

.img-1 {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.img-2 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  object-fit: cover;
  /*css required to get image on top of img-1*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642532744-d377ab507dc8?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=750&q=80" class="img-1">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1628160634750-a81a2a780805?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwyfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=600&q=60" class="img-2">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you must apply position absolute to both of children. Ans this way you can align them. Don't forget that you should give `z-index` a higher number to the first image.

```css
#topDiv {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 205px;
  background-image: url(/I/starry_sky.jpg);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

/* EDITED HERE */
.water {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  z-index: 1
}

.earth {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  /* YOU CAN REMOVE Z-INDEX HERE 
  z-index: 1; */
}
```

```html
<div id="topDiv">
  <img class='water' src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" width="900" height="205">
  <img class="earth" src="https://picsum.photos/100/300">
</div>
```